# Slow Download/Upload speed on KVM on Centos 6 server

Tags: kvm

I installed KVM on centos 6 dedicated server but the Download/Upload speed was very slow.
The operating system on KVM is Windows XP.
Download/Upload speed on Centos 6 is faster 10 times than on KVM.
I also installed virtual box just to check whether the problem comes from KVM but it appeared that Virtual Box Download/Upload speed was slower than KVM.
I also tried it on Ubuntu 12.04 server and the same thing happened.
I read several tutorials on how to fix that but no one of them worked.
This is a screenshot of my host device and device model https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q0Sz.jpg.
If i change the host device or the device model; Internet doesn't work on KVM.

Answer (score 1):

You should try and use [VirtIO](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Virtio) since Windows XP is supported in that, you should see a significant speed up if you use those drivers.